# Javascript SetForm via parameter in url

Tags: javascript, html

I try to change the SetForm by a parameter in my url like radio.php?land=form2. But it won't works. It does work manually via the  menu.

Its my first time i try javascript.

Hopefully some one can help. Thank you.

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const setForm = urlParams.get('land')
function setForm(value) {

    if(value == 'form1'){
                document.getElementById('form1').style='display:block;';
                document.getElementById('form2').style='display:none;';
            }
            else if(value == 'form2'){

                document.getElementById('form2').style = 'display:block;';
                document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:none;';
            }

}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onchange="setForm(this.value)" class="btn btn-secondary">
<option value="form1">Nederland</option>
<option value="form2">Frankrijk</option>
</select>

<div id="form1">
Nederland
</div>
<div  id="form2" style="display: none">
Frankrijk
</div>
```

Comment: You've already declared `setForm`.

Comment: I was try if hetake the value of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make some change to get this working:

- Move the first time query param based selection under `window.onload` so we run it once the DOM is clean.
- Change the variable name associated with value `urlParams.get('land')` to something else. Here I changed it to `land`
- Call the setForm method with the `land` so the page is initialized.

```js
   window.onload = function () {
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const land = urlParams.get('land'); // get the value
    setForm(land); // set it here
}
function setForm(value) {
    document.getElementById('select1').value = value; // if you want to update the dropdown value as well
    if(value == 'form1'){
        document.getElementById('form1').style='display:block;';
        document.getElementById('form2').style='display:none;';
    }
    else if(value == 'form2'){
        document.getElementById('form2').style = 'display:block;';
        document.getElementById('form1').style = 'display:none;';
    }

}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onchange="setForm(this.value)" class="btn btn-secondary">
<option value="form1">Nederland</option>
<option value="form2">Frankrijk</option>
</select>

<div id="form1">
Nederland
</div>
<div  id="form2" style="display: none">
Frankrijk
</div>
```